# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES
    at android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo.readFromParcel(ActivityManager.java:460)
    at android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo.init(ActivityManager.java:474)
    at android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo.init(ActivityManager.java:387)
    at android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo$1.createFromParcel(ActivityManager.java:466)
    at android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo$1.createFromParcel(ActivityManager.java:464)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getTasks(ActivityManagerNative.java:2092)
    at android.app.ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(ActivityManager.java:507)
    at android.app.ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(ActivityManager.java:534)
```

this bug happens in samsung GT-S7560, how to solve it?

Comment: Can you give some additional context? What were you doing when the error appeared?

Comment: I just use  activityManager.getRunningTasks(1) , then it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES`,
 it's a restricted permission.

From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES):

> Not for use by third-party applications.